# Image uploaded with Multer not showing in Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, multer

When using Postman the files are uploaded 100% to Mongo DB

When using the front end of my app - everything is uploaded to the database except the images

On my frontend I get the array of photos from

```
const getPhotosHandler = (e) => {
  e.target.files
}
```

and on the backend I have:

```
var express = require("express")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var {mongoose} = require("./db/mongoose");
var {User} = require("./models/users");
var {Post} = require("./models/post");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))

// Býr til nýjan póst í MongoDB
app.post("/newpost", upload.array('photos', 12), (req, res, next) => {
  var post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    userid: req.body.userid,
    category: req.body.category,
    price: req.body.price,
    body: req.body.body,
    latloc: req.body.latloc,
    lonloc: req.body.lonloc,
    tags: req.body.tags,
    photos: req.files
  });
  post.save().then((doc) => {
    res.send(doc)
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e)
  })
});
```

When I upload it via Postman I get the desired outcome: photos (5 objects) with-in the Post. But every time I try to do it via the front end of the app  I get: photos (0 objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload like that. If your need upload file via ajax request. You need to create an `FormData();`

Please read this article https://medium.com/ecmastack/uploading-files-with-react-js-and-node-js-e7e6b707f4ef for more details